# Не работает передача данных post запросом express

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express, fetch

помогите пожалуйста, не получается передать данные с помощью post запроса. Пытаюсь передать с помощью fetch и получить с помощью express, но получаю только пустые объекты.

fetch запрос:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Express получение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ответы сервера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вас не смущает что вы отправляете json, а ожидаете urlencoded?

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120)

Comment: используйте нормальный bodyParser)

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в том, что я отправлял json, а принимал url. Так надо было просто заменить urlencoded, на json